# How to output the configuration of devServer in vue-cli3?

Tags: vue.js, webpack, webpack-dev-server, vue-cli-3

I configured some proxys in a cli3 project.
After I put some old available configurations into this project, there was a problem with the proxy: The origin has been changed by default.

This is my configuration.

```
  '/gateway': {
    target: config.serverUrl,
    pathRewrite: {
      '^/gateway': ''
    },
    headers: {
      'appToken': config.appToken
    },
  },
```

As you can see, I **did not** configure the **changeOrigin** attribute. According to the [API](https://github.com/chimurai/http-proxy-middleware#http-proxy-options), changeOrigin **should default to false**. But when I use it, the Host I received in the background becomes the serverUrl of the proxy. And after I added `changeOrigin: false`, there is no such problem.

So I want to output the configuration of devServer to check the changeOrigin attribute.

I tried the `vue inspect> output.js` command, which did not include any information about devServer or proxy.
I also tried `vue inspect devServer` and `vue-cli-service inspect devServer`, they returned `undefined`.

So how do I output the devserver configuration?